# Java loop ignoring first input each loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a beginner and have a simple piece of code that works - it is designed to ask a user for seven numbers and store them in an array then print out what they entered

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] inputs = new int[7];

    System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers and a bonus ball");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        inputs[i] = in .nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("You have entered the numbers:");
    for (int i: inputs) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is add an error trap to make sure the number is not greater than 49 - I have added the following code and there are no errors and it runs fine but I have to add two numbers for each loop as it only stores the second input - can anyone help tell me why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] inputs = new int[7];

    System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers and a bonus ball");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if ( in .nextInt() > 49) {
            System.out.println("please enter a number less than 49");
            inputs[i] = in .nextInt();
        } else
            inputs[i] = in .nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("You have entered the numbers:");
    for (int i: inputs) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this line: `if (in.nextInt() >49)` - that *consumes* that input. All you're doing with it is comparing is with 49. After that, the value is *completely lost*. When you call `in.nextInt()` again afterwards, that's going to take the *next* piece of user input. It's not going to reuse the value you just checking in the comparison. Hint: you should store the value in a variable *then* compare it, so you can use the value later...

Comment: Thank you, thank actually makes sense which is the hardest bit when a beginner.

Comment: For the first example, you can just add an `if` statement, if the value is greater than 49, then decrease the value of `i`

Answer (score 0):

when you do in.nextInt() it give you the "next" integer in the input, so you are doing this twice for each loop cycle, once in the if statement and the other in the if or else body. so you need invoke that function only once. something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int [] inputs = new int [7];

    System.out.println("Enter 6 numbers and a bonus ball");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        int current_input = in.nextInt()
        if ( current_input > 49)
        {   
            System.out.println("please enter a number less than 49");
            inputs [i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        else
            inputs [i] = current_input;
    }   
    System.out.println("You have entered the numbers:");    
        for (int i : inputs)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
}
```

I don't test the code but you have the idea.
here you have another problem still, and is that when the user types a number over 49, the second time you ask the number to the user, you don't test again that it's below 49 so the user can enter any number.